# Footer is being affected by bootstrap c;ass

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I am currently working on the store page for my website and it seems that I have come across a problem. I have created a search function for my website. In the search.php page, however, where items are displayed according to the search, a bootstrap class seems to be interfering with my footer. When I remove the class the footer fits fine in the page but the product cards get messed up. When I add the class back in my footer shrinks and distorts. What can I do in order for that not to happen?

Here is my code:

search.php:

```
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $stock = $row['stock'];
        if ($stock > 0){
        echo '
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <form method="post" action="view_product.php?action=add&id='.$row["ID"].'">
                    <div class="products">

                        <a href="view_product.php?product='.$row["ID"].'">
                            <img src="'.$row["image"].'" class="product-img">
                        </a>';

echo'                           <div class="product-txt" style="padding: 5px;">
                                <h4 style="line-height: 10px;">

                                <a href="view_product.php?product='.$row['ID'].'">
                                    <b>'.$row['name'].'</b>
                                </a>
                        <br>

                        <h4>';
                            if($stock > 0){
                                echo ''.$row["price"].'';}
                            else{
                                echo ''.$row['outofstock'].'';
                        }
echo'                       </h4>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


  </body>
    
    ';
    }
}
include 'footer.php';
```

The "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ...." class is interfering with my footer. What can I do in order ti fix this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here are your bugs:

```
echo'                       </h4>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
    
    ';
    }
}
include 'footer.php';
```

First - double closing `</h4>`, you cannot have `<h4>` inside `<h4>`, but the real problem is including text of `footer` after closing `</body>`.
This happens sometimes, but you'd better use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/) w3c

---

update
That's how it should go

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $stock = $row['stock'];
    if ($stock > 0){    echo
        "<div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3\">\r\n
        <form method=\"post\" action=\"view_product.php?action=add&id=$row['ID']\">
        <div class=\"products\">\r\n
        <a href=\"view_product.php?product=$row['ID']\"><img src=\"$row['image']\" class=\"product-img\"></a></div>\r\n
        <div class=\"product-txt\" style=\"padding: 5px\">\r\n
        <h4 style=\"line-height: 10px\">
        <a href=\"view_product.php?product=$row['ID']\"><b>$row['name']</b></a>
        $row['price']
        </h4></div></form></div>\r\n";}
    else{   echo "<p>$row['outofstock']</p>\r\n";}}
include './footer.php';
echo'</body></html>';
```

The point is, you have to control your loops and HTML tags - what is open must be closed in time. If you get lost, take a look at the source code in your browser. And use the validator w3c like the best designers do.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that if I include the footer before it just repeats with everyproduct.